# Delete() entry box in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I am using tkinter and Python 3.8.5. I have the following two entry boxes that I would like to clear.

```
ketones_entry = Entry(screen, textvariable = key).place(x=120, y=75) 
glucose_entry = Entry(screen, textvariable = glu).place(x=120, y=120)
```

This is what I used to try and clear

```
ketones_entry.delete(0,END)
glucose_entry.delete(0,END)
```

I receive this error

```
ketones_entry.delete(0,END)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'delete'
```

Comment: place returns `None` so first 
instantiate then use the `place` method `ketones_entry = Entry(screen, textvariable = key)`  then `ketones_entry .place()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
ketones_entry = Entry(screen, textvariable = key).place(x=120, y=75)
```

You are creating an `Entry` object and then calling its `place` method. But place returns `None`, so `ketones_entry` is not an `Entry` object anymore but `None` instead. These 2 lines should be like this:

```py
ketones_entry = Entry(screen, textvariable = key)
ketones_entry.place(x=120, y=75) 
glucose_entry = Entry(screen, textvariable = glu)
glucose_entry.place(x=120, y=120)
```

If you need to call many methods of an object, you can use **object notation** :

```py
ketones_entry = (
    Entry(screen, textvariable=key)
    .place(x=120, y=75)
    .method2()
    .method3()
)
    ...
```